# What is the difference between rheofludification and thixotropy?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I'm studying chemical engineering and I remember last year in fluid mechanics lessons the teacher told us, Ketchup was an example of fluid which has the property of [rheofludification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_thinning). 
This year in chemical reactors lessons, the teacher said (answering a question) that the Ketchup was a good example of what a [thixotrope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thixotropy) fluid means.

I know that Wikipedia is not the best reference but when I looked on these two pages, in French (because I'm) I found this :

> Il ne faut pas confondre la rhéofluidification avec la thixotropie,
>   qui désigne la diminution de la viscosité sous l'effet de la
>   contrainte de cisaillement.

Which can be translate as "do not conflate rheofludification with thixotropy, which refers to the reduction of viscosity as a result of the shear thinning." Well I have no troubles considering Ketchup can have those both properties, however I don't understand the difference between both. And so during the time in which you mix it, it is more fluid than before.

I thought thixotropy was only the property to a fluid to become "fluid" when you mix it and turns back into a "solid".

Can someone explain it to me in an other way than shown in the wikipedia pages in which I'm not sure to understand everything at 100%. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something or I'm thinking too much and I think I didn't understand.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shear thinning liquids have a viscosity that is dependent on the shear rate, and only on the shear rate. Raise the shear rate and the fluid thins, and lower the shear rate and the fluid thickens. The response to the change in shear rate is immediate i.e. there is no delay between the shear rate changing and the viscosity changing.

Thixotropic liquids behave in a similar way but now there is a time dependent behaviour as well. Typically when you raise the shear then hold it steady the viscosity will decrease gradually before settling to a steady value. Likewise when you lower the shear rate the viscosity will increase gradually. It is this time dependence that distinguishes thixotropic fluids from shear thinning ones.

Tomato ketchup is thixotropic because if you shake it the viscosity will decrease but then stay low for some minutes. So before shaking you will find the sauce won't pour easily from the bottle, but after shaking the sauce will pause easily and will carry on pouring easily for some time. Let the bottle stand for an hour or so and the sauce will return to the on-pouring state.

As a general rule thixotropic liquids undergo relatively slow structural changes, and it's this slow change in structure that causes the slow change in the rheological properties.